# When taking snap shot there is a showing very little bit white background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

There are Two View controllers in one view controller i am taking an snap shot and in the anothe view controller i am showing tha anap shot that was picked.

I am working on image, i need to take a snap shot while i am doing this i am getting white background. I do not know why this appears? As below image (There are Three image views , Initially image view has a transparent image view then background body image view and tattoo image view.)

[image]

When i am taking the screen shot I am hiding the Background image. 
i set the view alpha to 1.0f, i set the view background color to clear color

The output screen shot is

[image]

My code is

```
    self.backgroundImgView.hidden=YES;
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.view.alpha=1.0f;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGRect rect;
rect = CGRectMake(appDelegate.xFloat, appDelegate.yFloat, appDelegate.widthFloat, appDelegate.heightFloat);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
appDelegate.tattooImg=img;
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Comment: you are pasting one image on another right?

Comment: yes i am saving that image and showing in another view . when i set the alpha to "0" the whole tattoo image disappears.  @Khoool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `UIView` like a holderview.... on the self.view. Then add both the images on the holderview not the self.view.... then wen u save the screenshot take it of the holderview ...